# How to handle whitespaces in paths in command line parameters

Tags: c#

I have the problem with whitespaces in my console application. My application is crashing because of not allowed chararcters.

My application is expecting an argument which is a path of the filesystem. So it will be called like this

```
myProg.exe "D:\tmp\with whitespace\"
```

With that information I want to create a file in the given folder, but this is not possible because of not allowed char.

```
String pdfName = "foobar.pdf
String datapath = args[0];
String targetJobFile = datapath + pdfName + ".txt";
```

I can see in the debugger that the targetJobFile value is

```
 "D:\tmp\with whitespace\"foobar.pdf.txt
```

And there i receive the exception. 
Thanks

Comment: You should use `Path.Combine`, it will handle issues like this. - [Path.Combine on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: does this line `String pdfName = "foobar.pdf` even compile? your parameter should work fine, as they are enclosed in double quotes

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the quotes from the argument, so before using it, use `Trim`:

```
String realArg = args[0].Trim('"');
```

You already have the `\` that `Path.Combine` would give you; but if you don't want your users to have to enter it, using `Path.Combine` is a good way to get the path separator character into your string.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just check for existence of `"` character and replace them before making the full path like

```
        datapath = datapath.Replace("\"","");
        String targetJobFile = datapath + pdfName;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go one step ahead and use Path.GetInvalidPathChars() which will return all invalid characters not allowed in path names and remove it from your path as follows -

modifiedPathName = new Regex(string.Format("[{0}]", Regex.Escape(new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars())))).Replace(PathName, replaceChar);